# Cant disable options in jquery multi select

Tags: jquery, html

I want to disable other options if first option is checked, else i need to allow user to select multiple options.

i tried different ways to disable the options in multiple drop down list but nothing worked.

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js"></script>
> <!-- Apply dropdown check list to the selected items  -->
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     $(document).ready(function() {
>         $("#s8").dropdownchecklist( {emptyText: "Please Select...", width: 150 
>         //, onItemClick: function(checkbox, selector){
> //var justChecked = checkbox.prop("checked");
> //var checkCount = (justChecked) ? 1 : -1;
> //for( i = 0; i < selector.options.length; i++ ){
>     //if ( selector.options[i].selected ) checkCount += 1;
>     //selector.options[i].checked=false;
>     //selector.options[i].disabled = true;
> //}
> //}           
>         });
>     });
> </script>
>  <script type="text/javascript">
>  function optionAlert(val)
>  {
>    var x = document.getElementById(val);
>    var y = x.selectedIndex;
>    var len = x.options.length;
>    if(y!=-1){
>     for(i=0; i<len; i++)
>     {
>       if(y != i)
>       {
>         x.options[i].disabled=true;
>         //alert(x.options[i].disabled);
>         var txt = x[i].text;
>         //alert(txt);       
>         //document.getElementById(txt).disable = true;      
>         $("#s8 option[value="+txt+"]").attr("disabled","disabled");
>         //var option = $("option[value='" + txt + "']", this);
>         //alert(option);
>         //option.attr("disabled","disabled");
>         //var curInnerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
>         //alert(curInnerHTML);
>         //curInnerHTML = curInnerHTML.replace("disable", "disabled");
>         //document.body.innerHTML = curInnerHTML;
>         //$('optgroup option').prop('disabled', true);
>         //$("#s8").attr("disabled", true);
>         //$("select option[value="+txt+"]").attr(state ? 'disable' : 'enable'));
>         //$(this).find("option[value="+txt+"]").prop("disabled", true);
>         //$(this).find("option:eq("+i+")").attr("disabled", true);
>         //$('#s8 option[value='+txt+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
>         //$("#s8 option:selected").attr('disabled','disabled');
>         //jQuery(':text:not(:hidden)').attr("disabled",true);
>         //jQuery("input[type='text']").prop("disabled", true);
>         //document.getElementById(txt).disabled=true;
>       }
>     }
>    }
>  }
>  </script>
> </head>
>   <body>
>    <table>
>    <tr>
>     <td>
>          <select name="drlOrderItem" id="s8" multiple="multiple" onChange="optionAlert('s8')">
>           <option id="Low"  value="Low" style='color:green' >Low</option>
>           <option id="Normal"  value="Normal" style='color:grey' >Normal</option>
>           <option id="Medium" value="Medium" style='color:orange'>Medium</option>
>           <option id="High" value="High" style='color:red' >High</option>
>          </select>
>       </td>
>     </tr>    
>   </table>
>    </body>
>   </html>
> ```

Comment: Make a fiddle of it on http://jsfiddle.net to let users help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
$('#s8 option').click(function () {
   var selVal = $(':selected').val();
   if (selVal == 'Low') {
      $('option').prop('disabled', true);
   } else {
      $('option').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: - http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/5d5XZ/1/

```
$(function(){
$("#s8").on("click",function(){
    if ($("#s8 option:eq(0)")[0].selected && $('#s8 option:selected').size()>1)
    {
        $("#s8").find("option").each(function(){
            $(this).prop('selected', false);
        });
        $("#s8 option:eq(0)")[0].selected = true;
    }
    else if ($("#s8 option:eq(0)")[0].selected==false && $('#s8 option:selected').size()==1)
        $("#s8 option:eq(0)")[0].selected = false;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
   <select name="drlOrderItem" id="s8" multiple="multiple" onChange="optionAlert('s8')">
      <option id="Low"  value="Low" style='color:green' >Low</option>

      <optgroup>
      <option id="Normal"  value="Normal" style='color:grey' >Normal</option>
      <option id="Medium" value="Medium" style='color:orange'>Medium</option>
      <option id="High" value="High" style='color:red' >High</option>
      </optgroup> 
     </select> 


1)  $('#selectId>option:selected').val();

   if (this.value == 'Low') {
      $('optgroup option').prop('disabled', true);
   } else {
      $('optgroup option').prop('disabled', false);
   }

2)    if($('#selectId>option:selected'))
      //your code
```

i didnt tried but i found this logic..may be it will help you..

Comment: You may need to improve your answer since it is of little use as it is now.